# c# Как спарсить XML файл

Tags: c#, xml, парсер

Имеется вот такой ХМЛ файл (Ниже пример), мне нужно вывести значение Nominal, Name, Value, в Label, прошу помочь.

```
 -<ValType Type="Bank">
   -<Valute Code="XPD">
        <Nominal>1 t.u.</Nominal>
        <Name>Palladium</Name>
        <Value>2560.3275</Value>
    </Valute>

-<Valute Code="XPT">
    <Nominal>1 t.u.</Nominal>
    <Name>Platin</Name>
    <Value>1383.205</Value>
    </Valute>
```

Comment: а почему парсить а не дессериализовать?

Comment: Наберите в строке поиска на SO "парсинг XML [c#]" - [там](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3+XML+%5Bc%23%5D) куча примеров.

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
 xDoc.Load("ИмяФайла.xml");
                XmlElement xRoot = xDoc.DocumentElement;
                XmlNode node;
foreach (XmlNode xnode in xRoot)
node= xnode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("ИмяАтрибута");
                    if (node!= null)
                    {
                        foreach (XmlNode childnode in xnode.ChildNodes)
                        {
                            if (childnode.Name == "ИмяВложенногоАтрибута")

                                //делать свои действия
                                //или ни чего не делать
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Спасибо за инфу, но node выдает ошибку (Node не присвоено значение)

Comment: Так же, внутри иф есть форичь, где xnode не будет видеться

Comment: ну как бы данный node служить для хранения значений и перебор идет по не node, а xRoot, по xnode, а затем в node = чето там....

Comment: Все равно ошибки(

Comment: Дмитрий, https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/16.2.php или https://studassistent.ru/charp/parsing-xml-dokumenta-c надеюсь эти статьи Вам помогут. Простите что не смог помочь Вам.